# iOS to Mac OS X [core] bluetooth data transfer

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, connection, core-bluetooth

My objective here is to create a connection between a *device running iOS* to a *device running Mac OS X*, via bluetooth. I know that I might be able to use CoreBluetooth for this but I don't understand how since I don't see a method to setup a service on the *iOS device* and broadcast it as an available service for *a device running Mac OS X*. In other words, I simply  want to setup a connection to get the *iOS device* to send data to the *Mac OS X device*. Also, how would I go about to specify how to setup properties of the service. I've tried researching this stuff but most of the documentation makes little sense to me. The data transfer is small so bluetooth is good enough for the job. I'm trying to avoid Bonjour for this, and the Game center framework for P2P since OS X can't handle that (I think).

Comment: Also, I'd like to use this on devices that **don't have Bluetooth LE** and to my understanding CoreBluetooth only works with devices with BLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS6 the iPhone 4S, 5 and New iPad can work both as Peripheral and as Central in Bluetooth Smart / Low Energy mode.
Try downloading "LightBlue" APP from APP Store. It let's you put the iPhone4S or 5 into Peripheral mode with random Services which you can then read from the Mac (if you have a newer one with BT Low Energy, I use the Retina for that but also the new iMac and Mac Mini got BT Low Energy).

You are correct that Core Bluetooth only give access to Bluetooth Low Energy which doesn't allow for the MFI chip.

Comment: Let me get this straight, because I think i just got my answer, so thanks. iOS devices (iPod, iPhone, iPad..) **without** Bluetooth LE **can't connect** to other devices (like my iMac) right? There's no framework for that, is there? I just found some article on the internet saying something about a MFI program or something but now with the introduction of Bluetooth LE there's no need for the MFI program right? Sorry, it's because this is my first Bluetooth application, but my device doesn't have Bluetooth LE, and I didn't even know what MFI is till I looked it up just now.

Comment: To make this even clearer, I'm trying to build an app from my iPod(4G) to connect and send data to my iMac. Neither have BLE. So how can I even do this? Is there some framework I missed?

Comment: You should be able to do that.
Take a look at this:
http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.UN98MqU473A

Not sure if you are allowed to publish app's using this though.

I think all Apple equipment sort of get "MFI" chips or something like that which enables them to use those apis.

Comment: I found using Bonjour with GCDAsyncSocket was the best way to go.

Comment: @MPX: it'd be great if you could post some code examples!

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across this today... and just wanted to give another answer to anyone needing to communicate to a non-Bluetooth LE device from your Mac.

The way to go is with IOBluetooth, and IOBluetoothUI. 
They are both frameworks for the Mac, and they allow you to communicate with both old bluetooth, and Bluetooth LE 4.0, I believe. Also, I'm pretty positive you can act as a Central and Peripheral Device using this framework.