# Send file from iPhone device to mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, bluetooth

Currently, I am working on an App under which I have to send files from iPhone device to my

mac through Bluetooth. So by searching I am only able to pair with mac system but I am not

able to send file to mac through my searching code. So my question is that Does it possible

to send file from iPhone device to mac? And if is possible then give me some clue to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Do you reaaly want to use bluetooth? I would sugest using WIFI since it is available on most computers and easily portable. But anyways you will have to find a working blutooth/wlan client for the computer/mac.

Comment: I want to send data through internal Bluetooth of device to mac in code.Does it possible or not in code?

Comment: It is possible but you need to be aware that it is rather complicated and it would be much easier to do using wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to transfer files from iOS device to a MAC machine using Bluetooth. It is possible if you want to transfer files from one iOS device to another using Bluetooth.

Comment: Are you sure bro that it is not possible in mac case?I know it is possible in device to device transfer but I am confuse in case of sending files to mac?

Comment: Yes I am pretty much sure on that

Comment: I am quite sure it is possible. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132867/ios-to-mac-os-x-core-bluetooth-data-transfer